# Значение слова ОХОТНИЧИЙ

Tags: словообразование, значение-слов, семантика

В словаре Тихонова А. Н. указано, что слово *охотничий* является производным от *охотник* с чередованием *к—ч.*

В словаре Т. Ф. Ефремововой указывается:

> прил.
>
> 1) Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: охотник (2*1), связанный с
>   ним.
>
> 2) Свойственный охотнику (2*1), характерный для него.
>
> 3) Принадлежащий охотнику (2*1).

Мне кажется, что *охотничий* может означать не только *связанный с охотником*, но и *связанный с охотой.* Например:

1. > Потеряна часть драгоценного **охотничьего времени (времени, отведённого на охоту)** — короткого зимнего дня, да и зверь может воспользоваться паузой и улизнуть из оклада.
2. > Если Вы очень постараетесь, то сможете найти в **охотничьей литературе (литература об охоте / про охоту)** о...
3. > *ОХОТНИЧЬИ ПТИЦЫ* — птицы, используемые для охоты.

Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

Здесь трудно что-то конкретное сказать. 
Охотник связан с охотой, так что использование "охотничий" в ваших примерах никак не противоречит ни вашему предположению, ни тому, что "охотничий" связан с охотником.

И по смыслу, охотничьи "птицы" - это исходно "принадлежащие охотнику". Аналогично и "литература" - для охотников. Да и с первым примером не все ясно. "Профессорское время" - это как толковать с ваших позиций? По мне так  это "время профессора", "отведенное профессору". Так и с "охотничьим временем" - это время отведенное *охотнику*, потому оно и драгоценное.

С другой стороны, есть прилагательное "охотный", которое связано с охотой напрямую, минуя охотника, но оно сильно устарело, поэтому часть семантики действительно перешло на "охотный". 
так что в каком-то смысле вы правы. Но для включения в словарь, боюсь, этого недостаточно.
(+)
А какой-нибудь словарь вообще приводит объяснение "связанный с охотой"? Тихонов - это все-таки словарь этимологический, да еще школьный. Тут надо хотя бы Кузнецова. Или там Ожегова, Ушакова - из старших если.

Answer (score 1):

Прилагательное "охотничий" **относится  равным образом и к охоте, и к охотнику**, просто в качестве мотивирующей основы выступает существительное "охотник" как фонетически более подходящее, а также более информативное и традиционно используемое в подобных случаях (пастуший, рыбачий).

Comment: *Прилагательное "охотничий" относится равным образом и к охоте, и к охотнику,* - А Ефремова о том, получается, не знает?

Comment: *а также более информативное и традиционно используемое в подобных случаях (пастуший, рыбачий).* - а вот тут я даже не согласан принципиально. В ***подобных*** случаях  выступает "рыболовный", "пастбищный" и т. п. "Охотничий" по отношению к охоте в этом смысле уникально.

Comment: Возможно,  в словарях речь идет о мотивирующей основе, а здесь нет сомнений: охотник - охотничий. Другую схему нельзя применить, так как суффиксы ИЙ, Н в современном языке используются в других словах: охотно, охочий (но: охотный ряд). Вообще говоря, этимология здесь интересная, предполагается связь глаголов  хватать - хотеть, а слово "охота" на зверя -  позднее, оно появилось только в 17 веке, раньше был "лов". Кроме того, охота  (в общем значении желать, хотеть) сначала называлась охвота, существовали прилагательные охвотный, охвочий, потом - охотный, охочий (материал из Черных).

Comment: *Возможно, в словарях речь идет о мотивирующей основе* - а у вас о чем? Ну ладно, у Тихонова словарь соответствующий, там и положено морфы выделять. Но у Ефремовой-то *толковый*, там три *значения* даны, о чем речь-то, при чем тут основа?

Comment: То, что "охотничий" от "охотник" сомнений не вызывает, да вопрос не в том. *Может ли "охотничий" означать "оиносящийся к охоте" напрямую, не через "охотника."* - и вот тут я не вижу неоспоримых аргументов *за*. Вроде и может, но все равно как-то опосредовано, через охотника.

Comment: У Ефремовой указаны три значения:1) Соотносящийся, связанный; 
2) Свойственный, характерный . 3) Принадлежащий . Вот в первом значении мы имеем связку/соотнесенность: охота - охотник - охотничий. Два других значения - только для охотника.